# Socketchannel always null

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send an EHLO command to an SMTP server. The connection succeeds, but I can't seem to read any data from it:

```
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = null;
    try {
        socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("host", 25));
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 1024);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        byteBuffer.clear();
        socketChannel.write(byteBuffer.put(SMTP_EHLO.getBytes()));
        byteBuffer.flip();
        socketChannel.read(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer.get(subStringBytes);
        String ss = new String(subStringBytes);
        System.out.println(byteBuffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output of the print statement is always \u000(null)

Comment: flip() must precede a write() or a get(), not follow it, and there's a large difference between the 'SocketChannel always null' of your title and the result of printing a ByteBuffer being a *null character.* Please amend your title to agree with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    socketChannel.write(byteBuffer.put(SMTP_EHLO.getBytes()));
```

You `put` the SMTP_EHLO into the buffer, but you must `flip()` the buffer *before* writing it. Otherwise, you are writing nothing to the socket channel.  From the `SocketChannel` Javadoc:

> An attempt is made to write up to r bytes to the channel, where r is
>   the number of bytes remaining in the buffer, that is, `src.remaining()`,
>   at the moment this method is invoked.

And from `Buffer#remaining()`:

> `public final int remaining()`
>
> Returns the number of elements between the current position and the limit.

So, after `byteBuffer.put(...)` current position == limit.

Comment: So no traffic gets put on the wire and neither is read from it, which causes the `read()` perhaps to return 0 after a while. `read()`'s return value should always be checked by the way, otherwise you don't know how many bytes you've received, which might be less than the buffer's size.

Comment: Thanks. That documentation could also be a little bit more clear on the matter though.

Comment: The semantics of buffer operations are a little counter-intuitive at first but make perfect sense once you've used them once or twice.