# why client can not receive message from server (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, client, nio

I have just started learning java. I modified the client side code for a server/client communication program, by creating two threads for the client side, main thread for receiving user's input, and inputThread for receiving server's response. I am sure that server has sent the response to client, however, no response message is obtain at client.

Here is my code. Can anyone help me to figure it out? Thanks

```
package clientnio;

import java.net.*; 
import java.nio.*; 
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class ClientNIO {
public static int bufferLen = 50;
public static SocketChannel client;
public static ByteBuffer writeBuffer;
public static ByteBuffer readBuffer;

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferLen);
    readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferLen);

    try { 
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",5505); 
        System.out.println("Local address: "+ address);
        client=SocketChannel.open(address);
        client.configureBlocking(false); 

        //readBuffer.flip();
        new inputThread(readBuffer);

        /*
        String a="asdasdasdasddffasfas"; 
        writeBuffer.put(a.getBytes()); 
        writeBuffer.clear();  
        int d=client.write(writeBuffer);
        writeBuffer.flip();
        */

        while (true) {
            InputStream inStream = System.in;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inStream);
            if (scan.hasNext()==true) {
                String inputLine = scan.nextLine();
                writeBuffer.put(inputLine.getBytes()); 
                //writeBuffer.clear();
                System.out.println(writeBuffer.remaining());
                client.write(writeBuffer);
                System.out.println("Sending data: "+new String(writeBuffer.array()));
                writeBuffer.flip(); 
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
        }                 
    } 
    catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(e);
    } 

}
}

class inputThread extends Thread {
private ByteBuffer readBuffer;
public inputThread(ByteBuffer readBuffer1) {  
    System.out.println("Receiving thread starts.");
    this.readBuffer = readBuffer1;
    start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            readBuffer.flip();
            int i=ClientNIO.client.read(readBuffer); 
            if(i>0) { 
                byte[] b=readBuffer.array(); 
                System.out.println("Receiving data: "+new String(b)); 
                    //client.close(); 
                    //System.out.println("Connection closed."); 
                    //break; 
            }
            Thread.sleep(100); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like you're showing server code.. but I don't see your client code?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your server and client don't implement the same protocol. For example, if your client is expecting application-level messages to be terminated with a newline, the server must send them terminated by a newline.

Comment: @Austin: what's shown is probably the client code. Otherwise it would  have used `ServerSocketChannel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not an active user of Java. (I only used it in school.)

---

Advice: I think it will greatly simplify the debugging process if you use *blocking mode*, at least until your code example is working correctly. (Currently your code does not seem to benefit from the non-blocking mode.)

---

I have identified two issues, culminating into four possible lines of code that may require changing:

1. When a `ByteBuffer` allocates its backing array, it sets itself ready to write by setting `position` to zero and `limit` to the capacity of that array. Your two uses of `ByteBuffer.flip()` (in the writing loop and the reading loop respectively) seem to be contrary to the convention.
2. Calling the `ByteBuffer.array()` method always returns the whole backing array, thus it always has size `bufferLen`. Because of this, a `String` constructed from the full-size array may contain junk from a previous transmission.

   - Typically, the array needs to be trimmed to the transmission size, and the conversion between a `String` and a byte array *must* use the same encoding as the server.

---

My suggested changes for first issue: 
*(Note: I don't know how to fix the array trimming and encoding issue.)*

```
writeBuffer.put(inputLine.getBytes()); 
writeBuffer.flip();                       // <--here
client.write(writeBuffer);
...
writeBuffer.clear();                      // <-- should be clear() instead of flip()
Thread.sleep(300);
```

---

```
// readBuffer.flip();                      // <-- remove this line
int i=ClientNIO.client.read(readBuffer); 
if(i>0) { 
    readBuffer.flip();                     // <-- move it here
    byte[] b=readBuffer.array(); 
    System.out.println("Receiving data: "+new String(b)); 
    ...
}
```

---

References

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html
- [Socketchannel always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871681/socketchannel-always-null)
- http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio.charset/ConvertChar.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I checked the server side, it did receive the expected data sent from client. I also tried your suggestions, but outcome is the same. I am thinking whether it is caused that the two threads are competing using the same socket.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I corrected the code as your suggestion. Now the client can obtain response from server. :P

Answer (score 0):

Calling `flip()` on a buffer prior to reading it is wrong. Don't do that. You need to flip it prior to *writing* from it, or getting from it, and `compact()` afterwards.