# Why my client cannot receive message from server

Tags: java, nio

Server：

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class TrainAgain {

private int port;
private Selector selector;

public TrainAgain(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void startServer() {
    try {
        //open serversocketchannel, bind to port,config non-blocking and register on selector .
        selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",port));
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        System.out.println("listen on port " + port);

        while (true) {
            //blocking here listening to channel that connected
            int r = selector.select();
            if (r == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            //after connected, use iterator to scan them all
            Iterator<SelectionKey> itr = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = itr.next();
                itr.remove();
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    //channel is ready to accept a new socket channel
                    ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                    ssc.configureBlocking(false);
                    //get the socket channel and registed it to selector;
                    SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
                    sc.configureBlocking(false);
                    if (sc == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    System.out.println("connected to a new socket channel :" + sc);
                }else if(key.isConnectable()){
                    ((SocketChannel)key.channel()).finishConnect();
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    //channel is ready for reading
                    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    sc.configureBlocking(false);
                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
                    while (true) {
                        buffer.clear();
                        int n = sc.read(buffer);
                        if (n <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.println("receive data :" + Arrays.toString(buffer.array())+" from "+sc);
                    }
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("welcome!".getBytes());
                    buffer.flip();
                    //I write buffer here
                    sc.write(buffer);
                    System.out.println("write data :" + Arrays.toString(buffer.array())+" to "+sc);
                }


            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrainAgain again = new TrainAgain(8000);
    again.startServer();
}

}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Client {

private void startClient(int port) {
    try {
        //get socketchannel and connect to server
        SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
        sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",port));
        System.out.println("connect to server from "+sc);
        sc.configureBlocking(false);
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\nio-data.txt","rw");
        FileChannel fc = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        //transfer data from filechannel to socketchannel
        fc.transferTo(0, randomAccessFile.length(), sc);

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
        if(sc.isConnectionPending()){
            sc.finishConnect();
        }
        System.out.println("connect to server from "+sc);
        while(true){
            buffer.clear();
            System.out.println("read data from "+sc);
            //blocking here, why can't I read buffer
            int r = sc.read(buffer);
            if(r <= 0){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer.array()));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.startClient(8000);
}
}
```

I'm a freshmen in Java NIO, and thank you for your help.
I have been debugged, and here is the output:

From server:

> listen on port 8000 connected to a new socket channel
>   :java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8000
>   remote=/127.0.0.1:62694] receive data :[82, 101, 116, 117, 116, 104,
>   101, 110, 32, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 105, 110, 103, 32, 116, 104,
>   105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 32, 104, 97, 115, 32, 110,
>   111, 32, 101, 102, 102, 101, 99, 116, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0] from
>   java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8000
>   remote=/127.0.0.1:62694] write data :[119, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109,
>   101, 33] to java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/127.0.0.1:8000 remote=/127.0.0.1:62694]

From Client:

> connect to server from java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/127.0.0.1:62694 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:8000] connect to
>   server from java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/127.0.0.1:62694 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:8000] read data from
>   java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:62694
>   remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:8000]

But in the end, the client blocked in the ***read(buffer)*** sentence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why client can not receive message from server (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889916/why-client-can-not-receive-message-from-server-java)

Comment: maybe not I think, I use **flip()** before **write()**

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
After debugging carefully, I found that after *wrap(bytes)* whose function is to set zero to the position of buffer, I use another *filp* method whose function is to set position **which is zero now** to limit. So the buffer isn't sent to client in fact.